# I2C address changing during operation for MAX 44009 ambient light sensor

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I have a raspberry pi project deployed and running which includes the Maxim Integrated MAX 44009 ambient light sensor.  It has been running fine using the default I2C address of 0x4A.

I stopped the running python program and restarted the program and immediately began seeing "input output errors errno = 5".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lumi.py", line 6, in <module>
    max44009 = MAX44009()
  File "/home/pi/max/MAX44009.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.write_config()
  File "/home/pi/max/MAX44009.py", line 53, in write_config
    bus.write_byte_data(MAX44009_DEFAULT_ADDRESS, MAX44009_REG_CONFIG, CONFIG)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I ran the `i2cdetect -y 1` and discovered its address changed from the default 0x4A to 0x4B !  Changed the program to use 0x4B and its working again.

So my question is what may be the causes of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reviewing the data for this question I realized I failed to wire pin A0 which means it is floating.  Pulling A0 high selects address 0x4B ; and pulling A0 low selects address 0x4A.

I would assume this is sampled during configuration hence why it changed only after restarting program.

```
PIN NAME PIN DESCRIPTION
1 VCC Power Supply
2 GND Ground
3 A0 Address Select. Pull high to select address 1001 011x or low to select address 1001 010x.
4 INT Interrupt Output. Use an external pullup resistor.
5 SCL I2C Clock Bus
6 SDA I2C Data Bus
— EP Exposed Pad. Connect EP to ground.
```